# Firemonkey TBrushGrab

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I would like to create preview window with whole floor view, where user can change zoom and pan.
I was trying to use this example for Firemonkey, but on XE3 and it doesn't work. Has anybody already used this? There is very little documentation about this on internet.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/FMXTBrushGrab_(Delphi)

Comment: If you provide more detail someone may be able to help you but just saying 'it doesn't work' will probably get your question closed very quickly.

Comment: @MikeSutton If you follow the link, there is very well explained and simple example, how should TBrushGrab work. On key-up event or mouse-up event, it should magnify memo content in separate window. This example is documented for XE2 and for me it doesn't work in XE3. Form2 rectangle remains empty.

Comment: FWIW It won't work for me either on XE3. I don't have XE2 to test against so can't rule out a hardware problem.
Maybe you should post to QC?

Comment: I've submitted a QC report on this: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=110470 please upvote.

Comment: @Mike Sutton. Just revisited this topic and found your link to QC is broken...It should be http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=110471
Hopefully that's why there haven't been many votes

Answer (score 2):

I tried the example on both XE2 and XE3 and can confirm it works fine on XE2 and does not work on XE3. The second window remains blank. On Windows 8.